# PLS in R: Predicting new observations returns Fitted values instead

Tags: r, regression

In the past few days I have developed multiple PLS models in R for spectral data (wavebands as explanatory variables) and various vegetation parameters (as individual response variables). In total, the dataset comprises of 56. The first 28 (training set) have been used for model calibration, now all I want to do is to predict the response values for the remaining 28 observations in the tesset. For some reason, however, R keeps on the returning the fitted values of the calibration set for a given number of components rather than predictions for the independent test set. Here is what the model looks like in short.

```
# first simulate some data
set.seed(123)
bands=101
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(56*bands),ncol=bands))
colnames(data) <- paste0(1:bands)
data$height <- rpois(56,10)
data$fbm <- rpois(56,10)
data$nitrogen <- rpois(56,10)
data$carbon <- rpois(56,10)
data$chl <- rpois(56,10)
data$ID <- 1:56

data <- as.data.frame(data)
caldata <- data[1:28,] # define model training set
valdata <- data[29:56,] # define model testing set

# define explanatory variables (x)
spectra <- caldata[,1:101]

# build PLS model using training data only
library(pls)
refl.pls <- plsr(height ~ spectra, data = caldata, ncomp = 10, validation = 
"LOO", jackknife = TRUE)
```

It was then identified that a model comprising of 3 components yielded the best performance without over-fitting. Hence, the following command was used to predict the values of the 28 observations in the testing set using the above calibrated PLS model with 3 components:

```
predict(refl.pls, ncomp = 3, newdata = valdata)
```

Sensible as the output may seem, I soon discovered that all this piece of code generates are the fitted values of the PLS model for the calibration/training data, rather than predictions. I discovered this because the below code, in which newdata = is omitted, yields identical results.

```
predict(refl.pls, ncomp = 3)
```

Surely something must be going wrong, although I cannot seem to find out what specifically is. Is there someone out there who can, and is willing to help me move in the right direction?

Comment: Please try to make your code reproducible, as we don't have access to your data.

Comment: Are you sure the data-format of `valdata` is correct? You do a lot of data-transformation after splitting your dataset (and don't use your caldata dataframe anywhere). And as Pascal said, please make your example reproducible.

Comment: I added some data simulation now, hope this should suffice. I do various splittings indeed, first to seperate training from testing data (by rows). Then I seperate X from Y variables (by columns), with a single data frame with all colums of spectral data (X) and various data frames each containing a single column of a response variable (Y). In the actual code of the PLS model building I refer to 'spectra', which is actually refering to the caldata dataframe. I also refer to HEIGHT, which is also refering to the caldata data frame.

Comment: I guess you don't need `data <- read.table("CALVAL_FWHM30_indices+spectra.txt", header=TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data)` anymore in your question. Also, `plsr` function takes a data.frame as input. You probably can avoid the creation of `HEIGHT`, `FBM`... and so on

Comment: I can somehow see where you are trying to get at, however how do I call the spectral data in the dataframe in the plsr function without calling the entire dataframe? I need some splitting prior to the plsr function to seperate the X from the Y variables.

Comment: Pascal, based on your indirect suggestions I have changed the code, please see above. I got rid of the creation of HEIGHT, FBM etc, and instead call these Y variables by their header name in the plsr function itself and by defining the data in the same plsr function. In this way, however, the plsr function gives an error stating that type of 'spectra' is invalid (a list), but unlisting does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the nature of the input data.  Looking at `?plsr` and `str(yarn)` that goes with the example, `plsr` requires a very specific data frame that I find tricky to work with.  The input data frame should have a matrix as one of its elements (in your case, the spectral data).  I think the following works correctly (note I changed the size of the training set so that it wasn't half the original data, for troubleshooting):

```
library("pls")
set.seed(123)
bands=101
spectra = matrix(runif(56*bands),ncol=bands)
DF <- data.frame(spectra = I(spectra),
        height = rpois(56,10),
        fbm = rpois(56,10),
        nitrogen = rpois(56,10),
        carbon = rpois(56,10),
        chl = rpois(56,10),
        ID = 1:56)
class(DF$spectra) <- "matrix" # just to be certain, it was "AsIs"
str(DF)

DF$train <- rep(FALSE, 56)
DF$train[1:20] <- TRUE

refl.pls <- plsr(height ~ spectra, data = DF, ncomp = 10, validation = 
"LOO", jackknife = TRUE, subset = train)

res <- predict(refl.pls, ncomp = 3, newdata = DF[!DF$train,])
```

Note that I got the spectral data into the data frame as a matrix by protecting it with `I` which equates to `AsIs`.  There might be a more standard way to do this, but it works.  As I said, to me a matrix inside of a data frame is not completely intuitive or easy to grok.

As to why your version didn't work quite right, I think the best explanation is that everything needs to be in the one data frame you pass to `plsr` for the data sources to be completely unambiguous.

Comment: Dear Bryan, thanks for the extensive yet comprehensive answer. I have attempted to adjust your suggested code to my (non-simulated) data, which is already stored in a single data frame, and managed to get the code running after a while. Strangely enough, however, the PLS model calibration finds different optimum number of model components and different values for various statistics (e.g. R2, RMSE, PRESS etc.), compared to when I build the model using solely a dataframe consisting of the first 28 entries.

Comment: I did however manage to create some sort of work around for the predicting problem. I defined `spectra` twice, once as `spectra <- caldata[,8:ncol(caldata)]` and a second time as `spectra <- valdata[,8:ncol(valdata)]`. I first only ran the first piece of code and build the PLS model, then I ran the second piece of code to redifine the spectra for the validation set. Then, using the original predict function, I was able to retrieve predictions for a distinct parameter using the spectral data of the validation set and the factor loadings/coefficients found in calibration.

Comment: Sounds like you are working it out then.  Just keep checking and double-checking your results so you know you can trust the final answer.  The author of `plsr` has a very good book covering the topic, and I think I have seen it online for free.